# What is the name of the function $y = \beta_{0} - \beta_{1} {\beta_{2}}^{x}$?

Tags: functions, terminology

In SPSS the following function

$$ y = \beta_{0} {\beta_{1}}^{x}$$

is called a compound function. I think this name is wrong.
As far as I know a compound function has the form:

$$f(g(x))$$

But my real question is:

> What is the name of the following function:
> $$y = \beta_{0} - \beta_{1} {\beta_{2}}^{x}$$

Comment: This seems like semantics.   Every function can be written as the composition of two functions.   In infinitely many ways.

Comment: I don't think there is a name for it, and most functions don't have names. If I had to, I'd say it is a linear translate of an exponential function, or perhaps a linear polynomial in $\beta_2^x$, or....